# Initialise a const char * const * with two strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, initialization, constants

Does anyone know the correct way of initializing a `const char * const *` with two literal strings (`"abcdefg"` and `"hijklmnop"`)? I read it was difficult/not possible to convert from a `char **`, but I may be wrong.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So you want an array of constant pointers to constant "string"s?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of pointers-to-pointers, use an array of pointers and initialize them like this:

```
const char * const strs[] = {"abcdefg", "hijklmnop"};
```

So instead of a constant pointer to string constants you now have a constant array to string constants. C does not allow initializing pointers with braces (unless there is only a single value in them), but it does allow for arrays to be initialized this way.

Comment: But what you just posted _are_ pointers... or rather an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In C99 and up, you can use a compound literal to create an array and use that as an initializer for your pointer.

```
const char * const *p = (const char *[]){"abcdefg", "hijklmnop"};
```

This is equivalent to using a named array like in Kninnug's answer, plus a pointer with an initializer pointing to the array by name:

```
const char * const strs[] = {"abcdefg", "hijklmnop"};
const char * const *p = strs;
```

Except for the fact that the array has a name (`strs`) in one and is anonymous in the other.

And also let me add that none of these solutions involves converting a `char **` to a `const char * const *`. The way they are constructed, each `char *` is converted to a `const char *` individually by virtue of being used as an initializer for an array element that is individually a `const char *`. There aren't any `char **`'s in the code.